# Error type 000582 when trying to create buffer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, buffer, error-000582

I am trying to create buffers around a point FC that has an acreage field. The point FC has some rows that are null and some that report an acreage of 0.

I'm running into an issue when it comes to the arcpy.sf.CreateBuffers line where I get ERROR 000582. It looks like there is a null value somewhere that is causing a problem, but I can't figure out where. I put part of the error message and the code below. I tried making the cursor code set up a field that has no null or 0 values to avoid any issues. The field going into the buffer is type Float.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue? I tried running the process manually in Pro and got the same error.

```
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\createbuffers_sa.py", line 31, in <module>
    units=get_value(4),

  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\gautils\utilities.py", line 19, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\scripts\geoanalyticssoap.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.token = auth_params.get("token")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The code that is causing the above error is as follows:

```
curFields = ["ApproxAcres", newField]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(memBF, curFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] is not None:
            if row[0] != 0:
                sqMeter = row[0] * 4046.86
                row[1] = (math.sqrt((sqMeter / math.pi)))
                print("Result is {0}".format(row[1]))
            elif row[0] == 0:
                row[1] = 8
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        if row[0] is None:
            cursor.deleteRow()
del cursor

# Buffer options
bufName = "Brownfields_Buf"
outBufLoc = os.path.join(wsGDB,bufName)
outBuf = arcpy.sfa.CreateBuffers(memBF, outBufLoc, "", newField, "METERS", "DISSOLVE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error because arcpy.sfa.CreateBuffers tries to output to a portal feature class, not a geodatabase. I was using the wrong tool..